# PHP: isset to modify HTML element

Tags: php, html

This is my code:

```
<?php
  $printhename = $_POST['username3'];
  if(isset($_POST['username3']) && $printhename == "Carlos"){
    echo "<h1 class='title123'>Hello $printhename </h1>";    
  }
  else {
    echo "<h1 class='title123'>You don't belong here!</h1>";
  }
?>
```

What I want to do is, if "username3" is not set, the message "You don't belong here is shown". Otherwise, if the name is set and it's Carlos, display the other message. I must be doing this the wrong way because it is always printing "Hello $printhename", regardless of the name that has been input.

I'd like for someone to shed some light on this. I'm new to PHP.

If it helps, here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="centerlogin">
    <form class="formlogin" name="login" method="POST" action="testing.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" NAME="username3">
      <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="login">
    </form>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$printhename = $_POST['username3'];` is in the wrong spot. And `&& $printhename` use the POST array.

Comment: also your first variable is undefined and use the POST array to check if equal to "Carlos".

Comment: btw, you deleted your comment I was replying to ;-) just saying. You asked me where to put that but was busy writing my answer up. Keep the answer you accepted, I'm all for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I figured where to put it! Thanks anyway :D

Comment: Carlos, please re-accept the other answer, being Mac's. It was also the first one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I accepted your comment anyway, didn't I? I think I may have clicked someone else's reply mistakenly. It should be OK now!

Comment: The choice is yours. I did upvote the other answer. I just didn't see his answer at the time of my writing up my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong here.

Place the POST array that you first assigned for the variable and use the POST array for it to check if it's equal to "Carlos" inside the conditional statement.

```
<?php
//  $printhename = $_POST['username3']; // this throws an undefined variable
  if(isset($_POST['username3']) && $_POST['username3'] == "Carlos"){

$printhename = $_POST['username3'];
    echo "<h1 class='title123'>Hello $printhename </h1>";    
  }
  else {
    echo "<h1 class='title123'>You don't belong here!</h1>";
  }

?>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="centerlogin">
    <form class="formlogin" name="login" method="POST" action="testing.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" NAME="username3">
      <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="login">
    </form>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember, "Carlos" and "carlos" are two different animals.

On an added note; if you want to avoid showing the "You don't belong here!" message, you can check if the submit was set first; just in case your HTML and PHP are also in the same file.

I.e.:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['login_submit']) ){

  if(!empty($_POST['username3']) && $_POST['username3'] == "Carlos"){

    $printhename = $_POST['username3'];
    echo "<h1 class='title123'>Hello $printhename </h1>";    
  }
  else {
    echo "<h1 class='title123'>You don't belong here!</h1>";
  }

}

?>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="centerlogin">
    <form class="formlogin" name="login" method="POST" action="testing.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" NAME="username3">
      <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="login">
    </form>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Sidenote:

Use `!empty()` instead of `isset()` for the text input, it's actually better for those and it checks for both; if it's set and not empty.

Answer (score 2):

So $_POST['username3'] will always be *set* because it's a field in your HTML form and will always be submitted by it. However, if the visitor did not fill the form field with a value, $_POST['username3'] will be empty.

So you probably want to test with empty($_POST['username3']) instead of isset($_POST['username3'])...

And since you are compare "not empty AND equals to 'Carlos'" you can totally drop the "not empty" condition. (If it's equal to Carlos, it's not empty!)

To recap, with the comment from Fred -ii-:

```
<?php
  $printhename = $_POST['username3'];
  if($printhename == "Carlos"){
    echo "<h1 class='title123'>Hello $printhename </h1>";    
  }
  else {
    echo "<h1 class='title123'>You don't belong here!</h1>";
  }
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was actually busy writing up my question when I saw the OP's comment asking me where to put it, but he deleted his comment *lol* - But hey.. he chose this one which I'm happy for, *cheers* and thanks for the mention.

Comment: Sorry to see that the OP went and choose my answer. I actually asked them up there in comments to re-accept yours. Edit: and now re-accepted lol

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP to this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username3']))
{
$printhename = $_POST['username3'];
}
else
{
/* If it is not set, redirect client */
header('Location: /login.php');
}

  if($printhename == "Carlos"){
    echo "<h1 class='title123'>Hello $printhename </h1>";    
  }
  else {
    echo "<h1 class='title123'>You don't belong here!</h1>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your replies — they really helped me a lot and I couldn't be more thankful.

I don't know why I changed the method to GET, it was POST before!
To achieve the look I wanted, I had to work the code like this.

Inbetween the "head" tags:

```
<?php
  $printhename = $_POST['username3'];
?>
```

The body:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="centerlogin">
  <?php

    if($printhename == "Carlos"){
      echo "<h1 class='title123'>Hello $printhename </h1>";    
    }
    if (isset($printhename) && $printhename != "Carlos") {
      echo "<h1 class='title123'>You don't belong here!</h1>";
    }

    if(empty($printhename)) {
      echo "<h1 class='title'>Log in, please</h1>";
    }

  ?>
    <form class="formlogin" name="login" method="POST" action="testing.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" NAME="username3">
      <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="login">
    </form>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any optimizations I could do?

Comment: `$foo = $_POST['foo'];` will emit a notice if foo is not passed with the form.  So usually you use the isset prior to assignment.  `$foo = isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : null;`